# Online P2P game: Establishing a connection between PCs without a matchmaking server

Tags: p2p, nat, upnp

I was trying to make a simple multiplayer (P2P) board game that connects players over the internet. So far, the only networking applications I've worked on only communicate with permanent web servers via HTTP.

After some preliminary reading, I learnt that most devices are subject to NAT nowadays, which makes P2P connections a pain to establish. I've read about 2 ways around the NAT hurdle:

1. Set up a central server to facilitate NAT punch-through.
2. Use Internet Gateway Device (from UPnP) to do automatic port-forwarding.

I haven't delved into the details yet, but it seems like NAT punch-through requires me to set up a permanent matchmaking server (for which I doubt is within my budget) and to administer it (which I have no experience in). UPnP seems like the way to go.

Would you say that my assessment is accurate? Are there any other options? Is there anything else I should take into account before designing/implementing my game?

*(I'm planning to write my game using Qt, to support multiple platforms. Someone has made a [Qt-based P2P file sharer](http://www.mayaposch.com/uds.php) using the MiniUPnPc library, so I'm thinking of studying that implementation)*

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do to avoid the issue all together is just require your end user to make a local version of the app server and forward the ports themselves.  Just give them an option to either "Create Game" or "Join Game", and if they create a game make them specify the port they want to run it on.  Then it's their responsibility to make sure that port is open.

Having said that, I recently went through setting up a matchmaking style networked game using Unity3d and I can comment on setting up a matchmaking server within that framework.

There are 2 pieces to the process, the MasterServer and the Facilitator, where the MasterServer just holds all the game related information and the Facilitator handles incoming connections to the server.

Because the MasterServer/Facilitator are only handling connection information, they're fairly light processes and you can just run them in the background on your home machine if you don't mind leaving your machine on all the time.

It pretty much regulates itself once you have it up and running.  It's not any more difficult than running a standard web server anyway.

I haven't explored using Internet Gateway Device to handle networking, but looking at the wiki for it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol), it looks like it's just a magic thing to handle NAT punch through automatically.  I have done little to no research on this method, but it looks like it might be something that has to be installed on the client end, which I feel like isn't what you want.  If you find a way to make it work the way you want, let me know; I'd be curious to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, SainTfactor. I've decided to take the UPnP route for now, which means not all users will be able to use the app. Not ideal, but it will do for now. As I mentioned in the title, I needed a solution that doesn't require a matchmaking server. This could change in the future.

Comment: @JKSH No problem.  Also, if you want a project with some networking code in it to get some ideas for moving forward, here is a test project I put together a while back when I was trying to learn Unity networking ([https://github.com/SainTfactor/UnityNetworkTest](https://github.com/SainTfactor/UnityNetworkTest)).  The networking code is under Assets/Resources/Scripts.